CSRF verification failed. Request aborted with JWT token in Django RestAPI
I am currently encountering a 403 Forbidden error due to CSRF verification failure when making a POST request to my Django app's API endpoint, even while using a JWT token for authentication. I've attempted to disable CSRF protection for the API while maintaining it for the admin panel using a custom middleware, but the error persists. Below is the relevant configuration in my settings.py and views.py.
I've tried to disable CSRF checks for my API endpoints using custom middleware, as well as the decorators @method_decorator(csrf_exempt) and @csrf_exempt, but the CSRF requirement still seems to be enforced. Here's an overview of the steps I've taken:
settings.py:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "spBE.middlewares.disable_csrf.DisableCSRFOnAPI",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:1337','http://localhost:8000','http://10.126.2.27:8000','http://10.126.2.27:1337']
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True  
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="Domocek API",
        default_version='v1.1',
        description="Breakpoints",
        terms_of_service="https://app.slack.com/client/T04RV3CLJ2W/C06KV8FSY3X",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="nikita@gmail.com"),
        license=openapi.License(name="License"),
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(AllowAny,),
    authentication_classes=(JWTAuthentication,),
    url='http://10.126.2.27:1337/',
)


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

part of views.py
class ProjectCreatView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



I tried disabling CSRF for the API while keeping it for the admin panel using custom middleware, but the issue remains. Here’s the relevant code from settings.py and views.py
